# WP_Query pagination not working in admin area

Tags: wp-query, pagination, wp-admin

I've created a custom plugin page. On this page, I list posts using [wp_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). It works fine. I want to add pagination, but it doesn't work, even when I'm using the code provided within [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query):

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

the_title(); 
endwhile;

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 

else:  
echo 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.';
endif; ?>
```

When clicking on the pagination link, it loads up new page with the same posts. Why is this not working in the **wp-admin area**?

Comment: What do the paginated URLs look like? Have you verified that `paged` is set?

Comment: @Milo How do I verify if paged is set? The URL looks like: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin_page.php&paged=2

Comment: you could `echo get_query_var('paged')` to see what it outputs. I'll guess that there is no `$wp_query` object on your plugin page, so `get_query_var` won't return anything. you could try `$_GET['paged']` instead.

Comment: @Milo echo $paged did not return anything. I did try: "$paged = ( $_GET['paged'] ) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;" -- it loads up page 2 correctly, but doesn't go any further, even though there are tons of posts left. Why? We are getting to a solution though. :)

Comment: @ChristineCooper I scratched around and came up with this, [`WP_List_Table`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table)(*[source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src//wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L0)*). This is how pagination works on admin pages, maybe something you can try and incorporate in your project :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Very nice find, thank you. Although this seems to be a relatively adventurous solution and may not be ideal given that this plugin we are working on will be released publicly; so aiming for a more *traditional* way to add pagination to wp_query on admin page.

Comment: @ChristineCooper I was actually thinking of extracting the integral parts from that code and incorporating that into your own pagination function, not actually using the class I referred to :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen If you are up for it, could you please write up an answer with the respective code to use?

Comment: `next_posts_link` is a front end function. it relies on the `$paged` global, which is probably not correctly set on some admin pages. you know the number of pages (`$the_query->max_num_pages`), just output your own pagination links.

Comment: @Milo Got it! Can you please post your comments as an answer so that I can accept it as correct. This solves everything.

Comment: you can add your final working code as an answer since you did all the work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Milo noted that there is no `$wp_query` object in wp-admin page, so we can get `$paged` via:

```
$paged = ( $_GET['paged'] ) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
```

Now that we have `$paged`, we can code our own pagination. I will demonstrate how in its very simplest form.

First let's get maximum pagination pages:

```
$max_pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
```

Then calculate the next page:

```
$nextpage = $paged + 1;
```

Finally, let's create our pagination link. We do a basic if statement checking if `$max_pages` is greater than `$paged`:

```
if ($max_pages > $paged) {
    echo '<a href="admin.php?page=plugin-page.php&paged='. $nextpage .'">Load More Topics</a>';
}
```

It is as simple as that.

### Update

To enable previous page you can simply add:

```
$prevpage = max( ($paged - 1), 0 ); //max() will discard any negative value
if ($prevpage !== 0) {
   echo '<a href="admin.php?page=plugin-page.php&paged='. $prevpage .'">Previous page</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christine Cooper, that helped me a lot. I figured out to enable the 'Previous page' link, so I edited the question and added it to upvote the effort. :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Very nice, thanks for the addition!